# How to call ViewChild in runtime?

Tags: angular

In Angular2 ,
I want to find my children components , that was declared in the template in run time.
how can I do it?
For Example:

```
@Component({

template: `
<cmp1 *ngIf=expression></cmp1>
<cmp2 *ngIf=!expression></cmp2>
    `

})
export class Component3{

findChild(){
// How to find cmp2
}

}
```

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with "at runtime" but this is how it's usually done:

```
@Component({
template: `
<cmp1 #cmp *ngIf=expression></cmp1>
<cmp2 #cmp *ngIf=!expression></cmp2>
`
})
export class Component3{

  @ViewChildren('cmp') cmp:QueryList;

  findChild(){
    return this.cmp.toArray()[0];
  }
}
```

`Component1` needs to be imported.

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

Comment: note that the ngIf  , the ngIf will show only one of the two component.
Lets say that the expression = true.
cmp1 will be rendered , cmp2 wont be...
When I will change the expression to false at runtime, cmp1 will be removed from the DOM and cmp2 should be rendered.
In this scenario how will I get cmp2?

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I updated my answer. A better way might be to use `@ViewChild()` as demonstrated before and move `expression` to a method and check this method in `findChild` like `if(expression) { return cmp1; } else { return cmp2;}`